# Memory taken up by functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a Voxel class which is being created half a million times. I have reduced the amount of data I am using, but it just occurred to me that I am not sure whether functions take up memory in a similar fashion as variables. How can I find out the amount of space a function takes in my program? More importantly, when I have 500 instances of a class, does that mean I have 500 instances of the function?

I can guess that that is most likely not the case (not taking into account inline functions), but an explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't panic.  Code for most functions (whether `inline` or not) only occurs once in the linked binary.

Template methods occur once per instantiation, because different template parameters result in different code.

In this context, `instantiation` means the use in your build of a class or function template with a specific set of template parameters.  Each different set of parameters results in a new instantiation, though for class templates only the member functions that you actually use for each instantiation are included in your final binary image.  More background [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y5ca42y.aspx).

For Visual Studio make sure you enable [link-time code generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), as this can further reduce code size by inspecting the full function set at link-time, as well as the usual [compile-time optimizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59a3b321%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that you should already have maxed out.  You can also use [/OPT:REF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) at link time to omit unreferenced functions.  This is the default for Release builds, but worth double-checking.

Comment: You should clarify "once per instantiation" - a reader could take this to mean once per object instantiation, which I'm pretty sure isn't what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is only one instance of the function per template iteration.  All the objects of a class refer to the same function instance.

Determining the code size of the function is non-trivial.  Generating a link map is the most general means of determining function size, but it takes some education to read.

Comment: +1 for pointer to map file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have virtual functions in that class - no, member functions do not take any space in the class instance. With virtual functions each instance has a single pointer to *virtual function table*.

Answer (score 1):

What takes up space when creating a new object is the object data, not the machine code of the operations on that data – if you want to, you can think of member functions as »normal«, free functions which are implicitly passed a `this` pointer.

For instance, from a codegen point of view, there is little difference between

```
struct A { int x; void foo(); };
```

and

```
struct A {};
void foo( A* self );
```

.

For virtual functions this is not entirely true because each virtual function adds a pointer to the vtable, but that's a different story.